# How extract a image url from data-lazy-src in html in telegram instant view

Tags: telegram, telegram-instant-view

```
<img width="780" height="417" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20780%20417'%3E%3C/svg%3E" class="attachment-jannah-image-post size-jannah-image-post wp-post-image" alt="" data-lazy-src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IFCN-Bot-796x417-1-780x417.jpg">
```

telegram instant view doesn't support embedded `data:image` values in `img src` attributes which my team use as a placeholder for lazy loading.

How can I extract the `data-lazy-src` attribute value and transfer it to an `img` in the telegram instant view?

Documentation for telegram instant view can be found at [telegram instant view documentation](https://instantview.telegram.org/docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract it with `image_url: //img/@data-lazy-src`. Accoding to the [official Instant View docs](https://instantview.telegram.org/docs#set-attr), you could set the target image's `src` attribute using `@set_attr`.